# Debian 10 bridge disappear after reboot

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, bridge

I created a bridge in my Debian 10 router like this 
`# brctl addbr br0` after that I add network interface on my bridge `# brctl addif br0 eno1`

```
brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.0030bdb2810d   no      eno1
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` look like this

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Set up interfaces manually, avoiding conflicts with, e.g., network manager

iface eno1 inet manual

# Bridge setup
auto br0

iface br0 inet dhcp
      bridge_ports eno1
```

Everything works well, but If I reboot my router, `brctl show` returns empty result.
In my `syslog` I have this strange line : 
`bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if youd nedd this` is that normal ?
PS : I disabled ipv6 in `sysctl.conf` with this line `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`

What I need to do to have my bridge when my router reboot?

Comment: Is `auto bro` a typo in your question or your config? Should be `br0`

Comment: @Lenniey a typo error in my question sorry I update this

Comment: The config seems fine, anything in dmesg or syslog?

Comment: @Lenniey In my syslog and dmesg I have this line `bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if youd nedd this` Should I nedd to add `brctl addbr br0` somewhere for startup ?

Comment: Wait, why does `brctl show` list `bridge-lan` as bridge name?

Comment: @Lenniey Ctrl-C error sorry

Answer (score 3):

The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Configuring_bridging_in_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces) mentions what may be the same problem, for Stretch and Buster. If your system has the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` (mine does not) you could try removing it.

Otherwise, I like your idea of adding the bridge on startup. You could try in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  pre-up brctl addbr br0 && brctl addif br0 eno1
  post-down brctl delif br0 eno1 && brctl delbr br0
```

The `post-down` line is included for symmetry and to make sure that the pre-up line doesn't fail (which would abort ifup br0) if br0 is ever taken down and back up.

A safer way is probably:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  pre-up { brctl addbr br0 && brctl addif br0 eno1; } || true
```

where the `|| true` prevents the pre-up command from ever failing and aborting `ifup br0`. Ref: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html

I don't think you need to worry about the arp/ip/ip6tables filtering warning you're seeing, unless you need such filtering. The warning is unrelated to your current problem.